# Off-canvas menu sticky

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, sticky, off-canvas-menu

I'm using foundatuon 6 with an off canvas menu. I'm able to get the burger icon sticky by setting the position, but is there a way to stop the actual menu from scrolling with the content? I've looked around and can't seem to find a solution for foundation 6. The default UX seems a bit odd in how it works.

A point in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39226703/foundation-off-canvas-sticky-menu-bar-to-stick-to-bottom/39231416#39231416 and link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409034/foundation-6-magellan-sticky-not-working-with-zurb-template-cli-install/38411825#38411825 might help you understand a few things.