# Foundation 6 Magellan sticky not working with Zurb template cli install

Tags: javascript, navbar, sticky, zurb-foundation-6, magellan

I'm trying to use Magellan in a cli install of the Zurb fdn6 template. The page is running fine but Magellan just doesn't work for the sticky nav and throws the following console error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

It would appear Magellan is *registering* because when viewing the source in DevTools I can see the `data-sticky` attr registering a value, and `active` class is being applied to the anchors when scrolling up/down.

However, I do notice classes that *aren't* registering are: `is-at-top is-stuck` and these appear to be what makes the thing 'stick'. They show up in the Zurb docs example.

In `app.js` I have `$(document).foundation();` and when the page runs I can see that the Magellan module is actually loading. But the sticky nav just isn't sticking to the top of the window, it just doesn't work in this setup.

I've used the following standard example from [Zurb Fdn Magellan docs:](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/magellan.html)

```
<div data-sticky-container>
    <div class="sticky" id="example" data-sticky data-margin-top="0" style="width:100%;" data-margin-bottom="0" data-top-anchor="topAnchorExample" data-btm-anchor="bottomOfContentId:bottom">
        <nav data-magellan>
            <ul class="horizontal menu expanded">
                <li><a href="#first">First Arrival</a></li>
                <li><a href="#second">Second Arrival</a></li>
                <li><a href="#third">Third Arrival</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've seen other SO examples fixed but they all seemed to use builds other than the Zurb tempate and generally loaded the plugins via standard `<script src="xyz">` calls.

Does anyone know what's up with this Zurb template example?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike F5, making elements sticky in Foundation 6 is a bit tricky and frustrating to be frank. You don't just get it in the first try.

In F6, to make the magellan or any element sticky, a **reference point** is needed to *activate* the stickiness.

In this case, you need to have a root `div` with the id `topAnchorExample` and then write the next set of magellan generating codes.

Try doing this :

```
    <div id="topAnchorExample">
     <div data-sticky-container>
      <div class="sticky" id="example" data-sticky data-margin-top="0" style="width:100%;" data-margin-bottom="0" data-top-anchor="topAnchorExample" data-btm-anchor="bottomOfContentId:bottom">
       <nav data-magellan>
         <ul class="horizontal menu expanded">
            <li><a href="#first">First Arrival</a></li>
            <li><a href="#second">Second Arrival</a></li>
            <li><a href="#third">Third Arrival</a></li>
         </ul>
       </nav>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

And try not to mention the inline css - width:100%. I guess you will take care of that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I see what you mean exactly, but it's still not working for me! I'm getting exactly the same result - Magellan registering but not applying the required classes to make it stick, and I'm still getting the same console error. Just to reiterate, this is in the Zurb template via cli install, using the Handlebars/Panini structure. I've tried it with in both `./src/pages/index.html` and `./src/pages/index.html` but neither are working.