# Foundation 6 - Sticky Nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I really can't understand the difference between what I have done and what the example in the Foundation 6 Documents is:
[foundation.zurb.com](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sticky.html)

The functionality that I would like is for when you scroll and go past my sub-menu it the sticks to the top of the screen... instead as soon as I scroll down from the top of the page the sub menu sticks to the top of the screen. The functionality that I would like is exactly the same as the image in the example Foundation 6 give in their docs.

This is the code that I have:

```
<div data-sticky-container>

<section class="panel-tan navigation-panel sticky"
         data-sticky
         data-margin-top="0"
         style="width:100%">
    <div class="show-for-small-only navigation-panel-icon">
        <i class="icon icon-add"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <ul class="menu small-12 column">
            <?php

            // check if the repeater field has rows of data
            if( have_rows('navigation_items') ):
                $item_count = 0;
                // loop through the rows of data
                while ( have_rows('navigation_items') ) : the_row();
                $item_count++;
                ?>

                    <li><a href="#item-<?php echo $item_count; ?>"><?php echo the_sub_field('item_title'); ?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile;

            else : ?>
            <div class="column small-12">
                <p>
                    No Data Found!, please enter data in the columns field in the admin
                </p>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>

</div>
```

Comment: Hm, shouldn't that be `data-options="marginTop:0;"`, not `data-margin-top="0"`?

Comment: Afraid this does the same thing either way.

Comment: Can you create a demo using the generated markup that replicates the problem? I think that would be helpful in determining whether you've missed something. Also, ensure that you're not just missing some of the JS dependencies for this, there are a few.

Comment: I've given up with it tbh and just coded my own version in Jquery... Wasn't too hard. Thank you for you time

Comment: May be this answer could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409034/foundation-6-magellan-sticky-not-working-with-zurb-template-cli-install/38411825#38411825

Comment: Max Lynn, what did you work out? I have exactly that problem here with F6: http://kad.abricot-production.com/