# Foundation Off-Canvas sticky menu bar to stick to bottom

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6, off-canvas-menu

I am trying to create an `off-canvas` menu with `foundation` 6 like it's done in the [official site](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/off-canvas.html).

When it comes to the `mobile` menu bar, I'd like to make it sticky to the **bottom** of the screen.

```
.title-bar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

But as soon as I click the mobile menu, the menu bar jumps away as if it was **absolute** instead of **fixed**.

Anyone had this problem and solved it yet?

Comment: Visit the link, edit the css code like this:
`position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 100;`

Comment: You can see the effect here:
https://jsfiddle.net/nuom3h5y/4/

Answer (score 2):

There are a few changes to be made.

1. The `<div class="content">` should be mentioned **inside** the `<div class="off-canvas-content">`. Off-canvas is designed to work with contents written inside its `off-canvas-content` class.
2. The `<div class="off-canvas-content">` should be pushed to use the complete vertical height. You can mention, `height:100vh;` although, beware of the [browser compatibility.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)
3. The `<div class="off-canvas position-left">` gets another class `is-open` added to it, whenever the menu icon is toggled. Like point 2, this should also be pushed to use the entire vertical height.

Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/HariHarker/nuom3h5y/8/) for your reference.

*Note:*
If you feel the transition is a bit odd, install `motion-ui` and apply some transition.